# How does the operating system post io completion messages for async io

Tags: c#, winapi, asynchronous, async-await

[IO completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx) need to be signaled when async IO completes. This can be done by the user manually calling [PostQueuedCompletionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365458(v=vs.85).aspx) or the OS automatically doing this when async IO completes. How does the OS automatically do this and on which thread? How exactly does the communication between the disk drive and the OS work in this scenario?

I tried setting a breakpoint on PostQueuedCompletionStatus in visual studio when debugging a call to [FileStream.ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx), but that was never hit.

Comment: Are you doing kernel debugging? how did you add breakpoint in `PostQueuedCompletionStatus`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - `PostQueuedCompletionStatus` is user-mode function... not sure why you said "kernel"... maybe you mean "mixed mode debugging"?

Comment: I used the "Break at Function" feature in VS and entered "PostQueuedCompletionStatus". I also observed that a breakpoint at "GetQueuedCompletionStatus" was being successfully hit.

Comment: In most cases, the queuing of I/O completion events is handled by the kernel in an arbitrary thread context.  You can't debug it from a user-mode debugger.  (There are exceptions, for example Winsock service providers use the [WPUCompleteOverlappedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Harry pointed out, the queuing of IO completion events is handled by the windows kernel. When IO completes, the disk sends an [interrupt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O#Signals_.28interrupts.29) that is handled by the OS. The OS handler presumably enqueues the completion message to the appropriate IOCP.

Comment: The details are way more complicated than that - the distinction between an [interrupt service routine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a [deferred procedure call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is just one example - but, yes, that's broadly correct.  The key point in terms of debugging is that the code runs in the context of whatever thread the CPU happened to be running at the time, not necessarily a thread that even belongs to the process or user that initiated the I/O in question.

Answer (score 1):

The OS will supply the status to one of the threads associated with the completion port. This means any of the threads that have called [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx) for that port. That link goes to further IOCP materials on MSDN.

Comment: The OP was asking about which thread adds the event to the queue, not about which thread receives the event from the queue.